# Best way to alias expression

Tags: c++, sleep, using

I'm writing a program in C++, and at one part I want the program to sleep for 1 second. I'm using the following expression to be platform independent:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(1000));
```

This line is way too long, so I want to use an alias for it. What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: There are already some [helper types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Helper_types) for time durations. You can of course also make a function with a shorter name which takes a value in milliseconds, and calls `sleep_for`.

Comment: Wrap it in a function? `void sleep() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(1000));}` You can add a parameter with default argument if you want to specify the time sometimes.

Comment: There's also them user-defined literals to make use of.

Comment: A lazy way would be to use a #define macro.

Comment: @SenselessCoder: A *very* lazy *and* careless way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using >=c++14 there are literal chrono helpers. It is possible to write:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1min);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, if you want an “alias” for that action, you can write a function for it. `using` and `std::chrono`’s helpers can go a long way, though:

```
using std::chrono::seconds;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
⋮
sleep_for(seconds(1));
```